# VBA Type Mismatch, connecting pivottables to slicers with For Each loops

Tags: vba, collections, foreach, pivot-table, type-mismatch

Below gives me a Type Mismatch

I was inspired by the commented and working line, to make a simple macro to connect all Pivottables to all Slicers. I have a large dataset for which I want to choose various subsets with the slicer filters and then see all pivottables update...

Now, I believe this is very simple, glad if someone can help me out.

```
Sub ConnectSlicers_Pivottables()

'ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Country").PivotTables.AddPivotTable_
(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"))

Dim SC As SlicerCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

For Each SC In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
For Each PT In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

SC.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (PT)

Next PT
Next SC

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tht same problem. Only code `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")` works fine. I activated the sheet and then used "macro" code instead of usind variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does not work directly. Just make a small adjustment by calling PivotTable by its name:

**sc.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pt.Name))**